# What's the part number of this connector?

Tags: identification, connector

I'm looking for the part number of this 14-pin connector or its mating counterpart. The pitch is 1.25mm.

[image: Front View]
[image: Back View]

Thanks!

Comment: What is the pitch? In any case, there are likely many equivalent parts from various manufacturers. So a single part no. would be elusive.

Comment: Pitch is 50mil/1.27mm. An equivalent part would suffice, I just need a connector that matches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The part number is Molex Panelmate 0537801470